# Generate Sawtooth Tone in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, audio, waveform

I'm just making a tone generator and I was able to find code that makes a sine wave of a specified frequency:

```
private void genTone(){
    // fill out the array
    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate/freqOfTone));
    }

    // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
    // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
    int idx = 0;
    for (final double dVal : sample) {
        // scale to maximum amplitude
        final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
        // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);

    }
}

private void playSound(){
    final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
    audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
    audioTrack.play();
}
```

And I know from Wikipedia, the formula for a sawtooth tone is:

```
x(t) = t - floor(t);
```

How would I implement that into the genTone function? Really the thing that keeps me from figuring this out on my own is how frequency can be related to period (period doesn't involve time like frequency does unless I'm missing something. I'm not too great with sound science.)

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Period= 1/frequency, if that helps you figure it out.

You can substitute this for your sample generation expression:

```
sample[i]= 2*(i%(sampleRate/freqOfTone))/(sampleRate/freqOfTone)-1;
```

Here is an [example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y=%202%2a%28x%20mod%200.1%29/0.1%20-1) of how it works.
Code is adapted from [here](http://michaelkrzyzaniak.com/AudioSynthesis/2_Audio_Synthesis/1_Basic_Waveforms/5_Sawtooth_Wave/)

Comment: I accepted this but is there a way to increase the amplitude? Even at max volume it's not all too loud and it needs to be quite loud. Is it as easy as changing the 2 to something larger? (Avoiding clipping)