# How to generate a tone of specified frequncy for a fixed duration

Tags: android, audio, frequency

I am new to android.

Can someone help me with a **non-deprecated** code to generate a tone of F frequency and S second duration

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17604968/4519753) but it uses deprecated methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rendition of the linked code, adapted for API level 23+, with a parameter added for tone duration:

```
short generatedSnd[];
int sampleRate = 44100;
float freqOfTone = 1000;    //Hz
float amplitude = 10000;    //0..32767 (0x7FFF)
float lengthSeconds = 1.0f;

private void genTone(){

    int numSamples = (int) (sampleRate * lengthSeconds);
    generatedSnd = new short[numSamples];

    // fill out the array
    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        generatedSnd[i] = (short) (Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate/freqOfTone)) * amplitude);
    }
}

private void playSound(){
    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack.Builder()
        .setAudioFormat(
            new AudioFormat.Builder()
            .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
            .setSampleRate(sampleRate)
            .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO)
            .build()
        )
        .setTransferMode(AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC)
        .setBufferSizeInBytes(generatedSnd.length * 2)   //2 bytes-per-sample
        .build();

    audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
    audioTrack.play();
}
```

This code has been tested up to 50s in the emulator, but it may crash at higher play times, due to the size being passed to `setBufferSize()`. Note it does not include other advanced features to help you handle arbitrarily long play times, such as 1.) streaming playback, or 2.) phase correction due to `float` quantization errors at values far from 0.

It should work fine for durations less than about 10 seconds, however.

Also omitted is the AudioTrack cleanup code (`stop()`/`release()`).